# Apache virtualhost include

Tags: apache, config

Connect the apache config files with the command:

```
include / usr / local / apache / conf / sites / *. conf
```

Create a file with two virtualhost.

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@as.com
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias site.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/pachko1/site.com"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@as.com
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias site1.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/site1/site1.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

But when accessing site1.com always opens a folder of site.com.

If they are interchanged, when referring to site.com will open site1.com

Always works feather rule, why is this happening?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `NameVirtualHost` directives:

```
NameVirtualHost site.com
NameVirtualHost site1.com
```

and then add the actual host names to the `VirtualHost` directives:

```
<VirtualHost site.com>
...
<VirtualHost site1.com>
```